# Execute a php DELETE request

Tags: php

i'm using a php script in my Android project to delete a lign from the database . here is the php file content :

```
<?php
$pseudo = $_POST['pseudo']; 
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','ract');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "DELETE from utilisateur where pseudo=$pseudo";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

I think that the main problem in comparing pseudo to $pseudo

Comment: Is the value of `$pseudo` what you expect it to be?

Comment: is your `$_POST` variable even filled correctly?

Comment: Yes , the value of pseudo is correct ...

Comment: Are you getting a error message? Is your connection successful? What is the expected behaviour? I'm assuming that `utilisateur.pseudo` exists in the database?

Comment: Henders , the problem wastn't the connection , and the utilisateur.pseudo exists , the solution was to add mysqli_real_escape_string . thank you for the answers anyway

Answer (score 1):

For god sake, protect your query against SQL injection :

```
$sql = "DELETE from utilisateur where pseudo = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pseudo)."'";
```

Comment: In addition, that's not an answer to his question.

Comment: This worked , but with mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$pseudo).

Comment: @RalphMelhem It very well could be...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE from utilisateur where pseudo = '$pseudo'";
```

Comment: allready tested that and it didn't work :s

Comment: I've tried to delete by comparing an "Int" value in the condition and it worked

Comment: So is the pseudo an int or a string in your database?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.